# Flutter: AnimatedSwitcher in Stack not animating in desired position

Tags: flutter, animation

I am trying to use an `AnimatedSwitcher` within `Stack`. This leads to very strange behaviour of the animation. It animates the respective child widget (a red box in my case) **in the center of my `Stack`** and upon completion it snaps to the top left corner of my screen(which is where I would also like the animation to to take place). When I switch back, the same odd behaviour occurs.

My code looks as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool _showMenu = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => setState(() => _showMenu = !_showMenu),
                  child: SizedBox.expand(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    child: _showMenu
                        ? Container(
                            key: UniqueKey(),
                            height: 200,
                            width: 200,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )
                        : Container())
              ],
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which produces the following behaviour on the tap-event somewhere on the screen:

[image]

Any ideas why the red box is not animated in the top left corner but only goes there once the animation has finished?

Comment: Your key should be a unique final one and not keep recreating the same one over and over again.

Comment: ok, I thought I was using a unique key by adding `UniqueKey` to my animating `Container`. If I remove this key, it will stop animating entirely (even though it indeed stops swapping position awkwardly as before)... could you provide a suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: you need the unique key... but needs to be a final global on that class... because every time the build method is called again, the one you have is ditched and created again

Comment: if I add `final key = UniqueKey();` on the class level it still swaps position... what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies, as @Marino Zorilla pointed out, in the unique key I specified for my animating widget. Once I removed this key and also changed the "empty" `Container` (for the *false-condition* of my ternary operation) to a `SizedBox` it works as desired.

Apparently, this has to do with how flutter works internally (when compairing the *element tree* and the *widget tree* to determine which widgets need to be rebuilt). If the widget changes to a different type (like in my case from `Container` to `SizedBox`) no key is needed for flutter to know that this widget needs to be rebuilt.

The correct code looks as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool _showBox = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => setState(() => _showBox = !_showBox),
                  child: SizedBox.expand(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  child: _showBox
                      ? Container(
                          height: 200.0,
                          width: 200.0,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        )
                      : SizedBox(),
                  
                )
              ],
            )),
      
    );
  }
}
```